# "We do not except..." - is this proper use?

Tags: verbs, usage

I received a reply to an inquiry and I am puzzled by this use of "except".

Is it proper to write:

> "We do not except apples."

to communicate that apples **may be** included?

---

I can see how the sender may have had the intention to write:

> "We do not *accept* apples." or "We do not *expect* apples."

...which would dramatically change the meaning.

The rest of the reply was really well-written. While I understand I should really confirm with the sender, I don't want to implicitly tell them that their writing was confusing.

Comment: If there was an entire email, why can't you tell what it means?

Comment: @Lambie Because the sender provides absolutely no other context that could answer the question I've asked them other than this very sentence. In fact, it read like a canned email with that sentence added in the end to answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

In answer to your question: Is it proper to write:

> "We do not except apples"

It can be correct but it's unusual.  It would not mean that apples may be included, but instead apples **will not be excluded** (which may of course mean that they are included)

As an example you might see at a border crossing:

> No fruits or vegtables may be brought across the border. We do not except apples.

Meaning that you can't bring any fruits or vegetables over, not even apples.

It would be more usual to use the phrase "We do not make an exception for" rather than "we do not except".  So the same sign at the border crossing might state:

> No fruits or vegtables may be brought across the border. We do not make an exception for apples.

However the use of this phrase does seem strange.  Without seeing any of the rest of the email I suspect this is probably a mistake on the part of the sender.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning in your answer that the more common way to phrase this would be something like "make an exception," as in "No exception is made for apples." or "We do not make exceptions for apples."

Comment: @Paul - yes, I think that's a good idea and will edit the anwer.  Thanks (and +1) for your thoughtful contribution!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked up **except** in a dictionary? As a transitive verb, it means

> to take or leave out (something) from a number or a whole : exclude or
>   omit (as from consideration)

-- Webster's Third New International Dictionary, Unabridged

The sender might have meant that apples may be included. At the same time, the sender might have made a mistake as well.

So you'd better clarify this point with the sender.

Comment: Yes I did, but I couldn't find any example of this specific use so it seemed like an uncommon way to use the verb.

Comment: It's a formal word. Dictionaries do not mark it as old-fashioned or obsolete, they provide examples that reflect its usage in formal situations.